# JavaScript intellisense not working with simple function?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012

In VS 2012, intellisense of jquery works but not my custom function, Here is a simple example,

```
window.g = {};

//#region Public functions

/// <signature>
///   <summary>This function will return the current page mode.</summary>
///   <returns type="bool" />
/// </signature>
g.isPageInEditMode = function () {
    return true;
}
```

This function does shows me summary.

Comment: Did you try putting the signature inside the function?  In some circumstances it may be cleaner than creating *.intellisense.js for each script file in your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting these special comments in a separate file called XXX.intellisense.js solved the issue,

```
intellisense.annotate(g, {
    'isPageInEditMode': function () {
        /// <signature>
        ///   <summary>This function will return the current page mode.</summary>
        ///   <returns type="Boolean" />
        /// </signature>
    }
});
```